# Redesigning my login script function. How to proceed?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am in the process of rewriting my login script. The whole point of this exercise was to keep my connection handler OFF the page as I have been told off about this. What I am talking about is this.

var= mysqli_connect(x.x.x.x)

So have had a go at moving this into a function.

```
 function openDB() {
include("/assets/configs/db_config.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect('x', 'x', 'x', 'x');

//$conn = mysqli_connect($config["host"] , $config["username"], $config["password"],$config["dbname"]);

// 1. Create a database connection
//$conn = mysqli_connect("x" , "x", "","x");
if (!$conn)
{
    $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
    return false;
}
$this->conn = $conn;
return true;
}
```

However, as I know I have mentioned this in another question I won't ask anyone to go back over this function in particular. Essentially no matter what I tried, I got stuck because the mysqli_real_escape_string protocol was getting errors (object instead of connection)

Moving on, I have some other functions that contain `mysqli_real_escape_string` usages so I wanted to adapt one for a login function use. Here's one that works. It's an update function.

```
function member_update($mid, $name, $address, $postcode, $photo)
{
$esc_mid = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $mid);
$esc_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $name);
$esc_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $address);
$esc_postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $postcode);
$esc_photo = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $photo);

$sql = "UPDATE member SET
mid='{$esc_mid}',
name='{$esc_name}',
address='{$esc_address}',
postcode='{$esc_postcode}',
photo='{$esc_photo}'
WHERE mid='{$esc_mid}'";


 $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);

            if ($result) {
             $numofrows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn);

            echo("$esc_mid, {$esc_name}, $esc_address, {$esc_postcode}, $esc_photo"); /*see id*/
$numofrows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn);
return $numofrows;


            }
            else
                $this->error_msg = "could not connect for some wierd reason";
    return false ;

}
```

Now, it stands, this is where I am stuck. I have tried to modify the above function into one I can use for handing the login. Here it is.

```
function logcon($user, $password )
{

   $esc_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $user);
   $esc_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn,$password);  
$sql = "select * all from users where username  ='{$user}' AND password='{$password}'";
 $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);

  if ($result) {
             $numofrows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn);
            return $numofrows;
            }
            else
                $this->error_msg = "could not connect for some wierd reason";
                        return false ;

 }
```

As far as I can tell, the logic is close enough so it should work. But it doesn't. I'm getting stung with `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` page side on this slice of code.  `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, $sqL);`

This is my login script as it stands (minus the CSS and form)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$user=$_POST['user']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];


//To ensure that none of the fields are blank when submitting the form if
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 
    {    


$user = stripslashes($user);
$password = stripslashes($password);

$db1=new dbmember();
$db1->openDB();                 
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$user}' AND password='{$password}'";


$result=$db1->logcon($user, $password);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, $sqL);


if($row[0]==1)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
    header("location:index.php");
}
        else
        {
            print ('<div id="error">Acess denied, wrong username or password?</div>');
        }
        }
        else
            {
            print ('<div id="error">Enter something!</div>');
        }

}

    ?>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the answer to your question, you best not be storing passwords in plain text, y'hear. For the record I didn't give you the downvote.

Comment: Appreciated, I plan to work on a hash system in follow up iterations. For now the plan is to get the script to actually run.

Comment: the error message says your `$result` variable is a boolean. `mysqli_fetch_result` expects the first variable to be a `mysql_resul` object. You have to return it in your logcon function.

Comment: `$sql = "select * all from users where`.. `* all` ??? Might be due to that incorrect query there.  It is the SQL in `function logcon`

Comment: Please don't ask a [duplicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17992778/285587) but edit the original one.

Comment: Furthermore you do not return a mysqli resultset, but either the count or `FALSE` if it failed. If you return `FALSE` you should `if(($result = $db1->logcon($user, $password)) !== FALSE) { // do stuff } else { //error handling` }

Answer (score 0):

in your function

```
if ($result) {
    $numofrows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn);
    return $numofrows; << returns a number
} else {
    $this->error_msg = "could not connect for some wierd reason";
    return false ; << returns a boolean
}
```

you return either a number or a boolean.

```
mysqli_fetch_array(result,resulttype)
```

expects a mysqli_result object (see https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).
besides of that, your code lacks a lot of curly braces.

Also, you don't have to upload this much code if the problem occurs in only a few lines of it.

Answer (score -1):

So I'm pretty sure my comments provide answer:

```
$sql = "select * all from users where..
```

`* all` ??? Might be due to that incorrect query there. It is the SQL in function logcon

Furthermore you do not return a mysqli resultset, but either the count or FALSE if it failed. If you return FALSE you should check for the error you gave back!

```
if(($result = $db1->logcon($user, $password)) !== FALSE) 
{
   // do stuff 
} 
else 
{ 
    //error handling 
}
```

And `function logcon` should contain something like

```
if ($result) 
{
    return $result;
}
```

If you wish to use the result.